# Maven Deploy IBM Websphere to Nexus - No Jars

Tags: maven, deployment, websphere, nexus

thanks in advance.

In brief i'm trying to leverage the IBM WebSphere provided pom.xml for deploying libraries to Nexus.  Created a simple portlet project that has a reference to:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.tools.target</groupId>
        <artifactId>was</artifactId>
        <version>8.5.5</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Thanks to other posts here, i managed to get through a bunch of other errors including the 401 Unauthorized, but now after successfully the mvn deploy command, the repository has no jar files.

[The designated repository after mvn deploy.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7OqD.png)

The settings.xml file is pointed at this Nexus, but at a Group, which includes this designated repository, as well as Central, and the IBM repo.

Here is the error i'm getting on build:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.273 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-04-19T01:20:39-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project project-portlets.war: Could not resolve de
pendencies for project com.project.portal:project-portlets.war:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
: Failure to find com.ibm.tools.target:was:pom:8.5.5 in http://nexus.host.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/central was cached in the lo
cal repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of
Nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Perhaps I may have misconfigured something?

Thank you again!
John.

Comment: I searched for the artifact `was` of the groupId `com.ibm.tools.target` . ddn't find it in maven repository, so you have to add it manually in your Nexus in the repository 3rd party

Comment: the IBM repo wouldn't have that, the pom itself indicated 'provided', and the following article shows the dependency, and later on it mentions that i have to deploy it manually, like you said, and like what i've been trying.  However after running the manual deployment, the items are still not there.  Reference:  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/localrepo.htm